# Auth0 en Nextjs solo funciona en desarrollo

Tags: javascript, nextjs, auth0

Tengo un problema con `next-auth0` que no logro entender de donde viene.

En desarrollo todo funciona bien, pero en produccion me pasa lo siguiente:

Tengo un menu con muchos botones, uno de ellos tiene un link a `/dashboard`. Si hago click en el boton, en lugar de ir a `/dashboard` la app me lleva a `/api/auth/login?returnTo=%2Fdashboard`, y me muestra la pagina de error 500.

Si yo refresco el navegador, puedo acceder a la pagina de login.

Si yo escribo `/dashboard` a mano en la barra de navegacion, tambien puedo acceder a la pagina de login.

Pero no puedo llegar por medio de un link/boton.

No sabria por donde puede estar dicho problema, ya revise y comente todos los redirects de `next.config.js` y no cambió nada.

Este es el codigo de `/api/auth/[...auth0].js`

```
// Node Modules
import {
  handleAuth, handleLogin, handleLogout
} from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

export default handleAuth({
  async login(req, res) {
    try {
      await handleLogin(req, res, {
        returnTo: "/dashboard",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("login error: ", error);
      res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
    }
  },

  async logout(req, res) {
    try {
      await handleLogout(req, res, {
        returnTo: "/",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("logout error: ", error);
      res.status(error.status || 500).end(error.message);
    }
  },
});
```